# How to set Incremented value in nodes of neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a couple of nodes and I need to add a incremental value in all nodes of a particular label.

```
match wd= (w:MYNODE)
 forEach(n IN nodes(wd)|
  set n.incrementalId=??
);
```

currently I have tried for each to traverse on each node but unable to get index of the each loop
ps: I have also tried with but unable to increment ie ++ the current value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more succinct version of @InverseFalcon's first query (and resembles the form of the query in your question):

```
MATCH (w:MYNODE)
WITH COLLECT(w) as ws
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ws)-1) | SET (ws[i]).incrementalId = i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes already exist, then you'll have to use a more awkward approach using collections and indexes:

```
MATCH (w:MYNODE)
WITH collect(w) as myNodes
UNWIND range(0, size(myNodes)-1) as index
WITH index, myNodes[index] as node
SET node.incrementalId = index
```

If the nodes don't already exist, and you want to create some number of them with incremental ids, then it's an easier task using the `range()` function to produce a list of indexes:

```
UNWIND range(1, 100) as id
CREATE (:MYNODE {id:id})
```